# How to secure my data in sdcard so that no body can delete in android?

Tags: android, security, android-sdcard

Is there anyway that I can secure my data after I store the data in SDCard. I can encode it using Base64 so that it can't readable but how to secure it so that no body can delete.

Any ideas, Please share.

Comment: SD card however can be formatted, your best bet to save sensitive data is to save it in the App folder (Which is not accessible from a non-rooted phone)

Comment: `I can encode it using Base64 so that it can't readable` - you need something better than this.  I can recognise Base64 by looking at it.  It then takes me 15 seconds to decode.

Comment: any other suggestions on this.

Comment: Can we lock the folder which contains sensitive data, so that when anybody tries to delete it will display to enter password? Any thoughts?